# VIM mapping normal mode key sequences

Tags: vim

I can run

```sh
:execute "norm! mqI//\<esc>`q"
```

from the editor but when I try and make a mapping in my `.vimrc` file

```sh
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap -c :execute "norm! mqI//\<esc>`q"
```

I get the following error:

```sh
E114: Missing quote: "norm! mqI//\
E15: Invalid expression: "norm! mqI//\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from `\<esc>` instead you can use `\e`

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use the special `:help key-notation` inside double-quoted strings when the `<key>` is preceded with a `\`, like this:

```
:execute "norm! mqI//\<esc>`q"
```

In a mapping, however, the `<key>` is interpreted directly, and Vim treats the literal `<Esc>` as aborting the command-line. To fix that, you'd have to escape the `<esc>` as `<lt>esc>`:

```
nnoremap -c :execute "norm! mqI//\<lt>esc>`q"
```

However, this is complicating things too much. Actually, `:noremap` is equivalent to using `:normal!`, so you can skip the command-line altogether, and just define this:

```
nnoremap -c mqI//<esc>`q
```

#### autocmd vs. ftplugin

I would recommend putting the mapping (and any other C++-related settings) into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType cpp`; this requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.

#### commenter plugins

It looks like you are building a mapping to comment out lines. Please note that there are several commenter plugins that do this very well, and those are generic (and often extensible) so that they work for any filetype:

- [NERD Commenter plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [tComment plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Pretty new to vim so I am working on doing some stuff by hand to get started but will definitely check out those plugins.

Comment: If the `\<Esc>` inside the double quote is interpreted by Vim to abort the command line, why does the incomplete execute command get executed? Nothing should happen if that is the case.